# How to get program file from PIC?

Tags: pic, embedded, communication, microchip, programming

I want to get the program file in the pic 18F46K22 from an electronic PCB.  There is no code protection or password on the PIC18F46K22. It is a simple card. Is it possible to connect to the card with the Pickit 3 programmer and get the code?

Actually, I tried to connect to the PIC with Pickit3, but I got a warning that access to the Pickit3 path is denied. I have shared the warning pictures below, but not in English.

[image: device not seen. when ı click check connection, ı got device no found]

[image: Access denied to path pickit3]

The translation of the warning message above:

*An unprocessed unusual case happened in your app. If you click Continue the app will ignore the error and will try to continue. If you click Exit the app will be closed immediately.*

*Access to the path C:...\PICkit3.ini is denied.*

*---Installed Builds---*

*{Builds List}*

Comment: There were several issues regarding programming 18F46K22 family with PICkit3. Take a look at [here](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m552373.aspx) -- it explains a patch.

Comment: Thank you for your supporting @Rohat kılıç As far as my resarching can be get hex file from Pic also you can upload same hex file  another pic but you cant change something over code .In fact, it is possible to change something through the code, but this process is very difficult and challenging. I have no idea how it's done

Answer (score 2):

The standalone PICKit3 programming tool you are using, [PICkit 3 Programmer App and Scripting Tool v3.10](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkit3%20Programmer%20Application%20v3.10.zip), does not play well with non-English version of Windows newer than Windows XP.

It does work for me with Windows 10 but I needed to install it in a custom folder path.

In my case I installed it in this folder path: "E:\Apps\PIC_dev\PICkit 3 v3".

Just about anything will work as long as it is not the default path: "C:\Program Files (x86)".

The Windows OS tries to protect the "Program Files" folders in "special" ways that will cause applications developed for older versions of Windows to fail in odd ways.

This is where I suspect is your issue with the PICKit3 application is.